# How to search by country by country code in ngx-intl-tel-input

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ngx-international-phone-number

I am using [this stackblitz link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-intl-tel-input-demo-ng-12) to implement phone number field in my application
However I noticed that we cannot search country by typing country code such as +231 in country search dropdown. If I type country name then it takes me to the country but by code it is not working.

Can someone help me to either write a logic that will not allow user to enter numbers or help in search using country code also.

Search by country name

[image: Search by country name is working fine although I would have preffered if it removed other results]

Search by country code does nothing

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes sure, have a look at the options you can pass as input: https://github.com/webcat12345/ngx-intl-tel-input#options

Look at the `SearchCountryField` enum - it has `DialCode` available.

Adding that to your `searchCountryField` array will enable searching by dial code.

Comment: I implemented the following code but it doesn't seem to be working.  [searchCountryField]="[
          SearchCountryField.Iso2,
          SearchCountryField.Name,
          SearchCountryField.DialCode
        ]"
New stackblitz link: https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-intl-tel-input-demo-ng-12-put7re?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts,node_modules%2Fngx-intl-tel-input%2Flib%2Fenums%2Fsearch-country-field.enum.d.ts

Comment: Your stackblitz example is working fine for me. I clicked on the flags dropdown to open the country search panel - entering a number finds the associated country. Or did you have a different expectation maybe?

Comment: @CptKitkat I see your issue, you are searching with the appended `+` symbol. Try only numbers.